# How to add Ajax response to div in html

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

How to append Ajax response to div in HTML

This is my ajax Code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.credit,.debit').change(function(){
        var value=$(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"<?php echo base_url();>index.php/Transactions/getamountbyid",
            data:{id:value},
            success:function(result){
                console.log(result);
                $(".bal").html(result);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

This is my controller Code

```
public function getamountbyid(){
    $id=$this->input->post('id');
    $this->Transaction_model->getamountbyid($id);
    print_r($data1);
}
```

And THIS is my Ajax Response

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [Accounts_id] => 1 [Accounts_number] => 123123123 [Account_Name] => Qualight [account_nickname] => Qualight [Address] => hyderabad [Mobile] => 9123912345 [account_type] => 1 [PAN_NO] => 1231231231 [GST_NO] => 123 [credit] => 20000.00 [debit] => [balance] => 20000.00 [Time_stamp] => 2020-02-13 18:51:49 ) )
```

I want to display account debit and credit balance after selecting the account from drop down it should be display below drop down can you please help me how to append required response data to required field or div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, change `print_r($data1);` to `return json_encode($data1);` if return doesn't work then try echo.
Next, change `$(".bal").html(result);` to `$(".bal").html( result[0].credit+"<br>"+result[0].debit);`

Comment: its Working after adding of var json = JSON.parse(result);,Thanks @jeff for help

Answer (score 0):

if you only want to append then you need to use append() function. else Please provide the HTML as well so that I can understand your requirement and concept

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a div with identifier where you want to show the credit/debit and populate this div with in ajax response.

Firstly, use json_encode()

```
public function getamountbyid(){
         $id=$this->input->post('id');
$this->Transaction_model->getamountbyid($id);
**print_r(json_encode($data1));**
    }
```

Then, use

```
$("#target-div").append(JSON.stringify(data));

success: function (data) {
            for(var key in data) {
            var value = data[key];
                html+='<div>'+key+':'+value+'</div>'
            }
            $("#target-div").append(html);
```